# GLFT with Basis Universal texture in Three.js: Is mipmap required?

Tags: three.js, textures, gltf

I change a PNG texture of a GLTF file to Basis Universal and try to read it through the GLTFLoader of Three.js.
I use basisu executale from https://github.com/BinomialLLC/basis_universal.

Loading a texture which was converted using -mipmap option of basisu executable is successful. The textures looks well.
But when a GLTF file with a basis texture which was converted without -mipmap option is loaded, it looks all black. I would like to load also texture not having mipmap.

Am I missing something? Or is mipmap required to load Basis texture in Three.js ?
I learned how to use BasisTextureLoader and GLTFLoader from Three.js documents. And my initialize code is like the attached code.

https://threejs.org/docs/?=GLTF#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/BasisTextureLoader

```
    let basisLoader = new BasisTextureLoader()
    .setTranscoderPath('examples/js/libs/basis/');
    .detectSupport(viewer.renderer);
    THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.addHandler(/\.basis$/i, basisLoader);   

    let dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader().setDecoderPath( 'examples/js/libs/libs/draco/' );

    let gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
    .setCrossOrigin('anonymous')
    .setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );
```

Answer (score 4):

To use Basis Universal compression in a glTF file, don't use the `.basis` format or BasisTextureLoader – the standardized way to do that is with a `.ktx2` file. There's an [artist guide for updating a glTF asset to use `.ktx2` textures](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/3D-Formats-Guidelines/blob/main/KTXArtistGuide.md) available, which includes some details on mipmaps. You'll almost always need mipmaps, unless you know enough about mipmap filtering to be sure you can disable it without causing rendering issues (this is rare).

three.js provides an [example of how to load these files](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=compress#webgl_loader_gltf_compressed), which would look something like this:

```js
const ktx2Loader = new KTX2Loader()
  .setTranscoderPath( 'path/to/basis/transcoder/' )
  .detectSupport( renderer );

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.setKTX2Loader( ktx2Loader );
loader.load( 'path/to/model.glb', function ( gltf ) {

 ...

}, undefined, console.error );
```

Comment: The KTX2 pipeline you've mentioned was very helpful to me. I appreciate it. However, my application uses LOD meshes and dedicated textures per LOD mesh. I think mipmap is redundant to LOD data in this case. 

I found your answer to a question which same to mine and it works well to me. Thank you very much!

Q. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16524#issuecomment-584169504

A. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/compressed-texture-workflow-gltf-basis/10039/11?u=johannesdeml